# Calculating $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\log(\cos(x))}{x}$ where the domain of the quotient is $(0, \pi/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Calculating:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{\log(\cos(x))}{x}$$ where the domain of the quotient is $(0, \pi/2)$

The fist step is setting $f(x)=\log(\cos(x))$ and $g(x)=x$, and verifying their limits at $ 0$ and $ \pi /2$.

And here is where i have trouble, because the L´ Hospital rules for $0/0$ case says that $f, g$ must be definded at $[0, \pi /2]$, and $\log(\cos (\pi /2))$ is $-\infty$.

Comment: There is no need to verify the limit at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ if you are looking for the limit at $0$.

Comment: Then forget L'Hospital and switch to more direct methods.

Comment: @Did Not really the answer you should give here. L'Hospital works just fine on this problem.

Comment: Defined at $(0,h)$ for some $h>0$. Is a *limit*.

Comment: @5xum Well, this is my spontaneous reaction when I see how the user is basically lost and *prevented to think* by their focussing on L'H. Thus, yes I "should" very much mention the fact.

Comment: I think i´ve got confused because the quotient is the onde definded at $(0, \pi /2)$, not $f$.

Comment: You could use the squeeze theorem. With an upper bound of $\tan(x)$ and a lower bound of $-\tan(x)$. Both of these go to 0 at their right handed limits. Thus, your function does as well.

Comment: L'Hôpital's theorem only requires that the functions are defined in a (complete/right/left) neighborhood of $0$ ($0$ not necessarily included, as you're computing the limit) and that the limit at $0$ (from the right/left, if required) of both functions is $0$ or $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately, $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$, $\ln a^b=b\ln a$, $\ln(1+t)\sim t$ for $t\to0$, and $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin t}t=1$.

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln\cos x}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}}x=\frac12\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2x)}x=-\frac12\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin^2x}x$$

Can you take it from here? :-) P.S.: It would have been more interesting with $x^2$ instead of *x* in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating a limit of the expression as $x$ approaches $0$. There is no need for the expression to be defined at $\pi/2$, it must only be defined on $(0,\epsilon)$ for some small value of $\epsilon$. Your expression, for example, is defined on $(0,\pi/2)$, just not at $\pi/2$. That is all you need to use the l'Hospital rule and calculate the limit.

Comment: I think i´ve got confused because the quotient is the onde definded at $(0, \pi /2)$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital rule doesn't depend on the interval but rather on the derivation ratio in the limiting point, there is no expanding functions to an interval, limit is after all value in one point! not on the interval, so your problem should be tackled only from the point of $x \rightarrow 0 $ and the close space of this point. You should only calculate derivations and see the calculus through. L'Hospital rule doesn't rely on the function definition on the interval, consider functions like:

$f(x)=-\infty$ for $x \in ([0,\pi]+2k\pi) $ and

$f(x)=sinx$ for $x \in ([\pi,2\pi]+2k\pi) $

Can you calculate the following limit $lim_{x \rightarrow 3\pi/2} f(x)/(x-3\pi/2)$ ?!?!